# How to create batch that runs multiple commands for output files

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I am creating a batch file and I need it to run 2 different scripts on files in a folder with potentially hundreds of files.

The 1st script (abc2xyz) converts a file from .abc to .xyz

The 2nd script (procxyz) processes the .xyz

```
for %%f in (*.abc) do (
    abc2xyz %%f
    procxyz *.xyz
    )
```

The 1st script outputs .xyz just fine.

The 2nd script repeats running on ALL converted xyz files in the folder following each converted file instead of running on just the one that was just converted.

I can probably guess *.xyz is a problem, but how would I change this to process on the recent converted file instead of all .xyz files each time a file is converted?

Comment: Because of each iteration of the loop, you re-preocess all `.xyz` files. you need to change your approach here. Rename the file, then process the renamed files. Let me post an answer for you.

Comment: Thank you, Gerhard. I do need to keep the original file name from file.abc as file.xyz.

Comment: Yes, but you need to iterate each file, not all at once each itteration, the example in my answer shows you how to do that.

Comment: Just change `procxyz *.xyz` by `procxyz %%~Nf.xyz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you enter the loop, each command is executed, in this case, you are using a wildcard `*.xyz` and therefore each `xyz` file will be processed, so if you want to do it per file, you need to use variable expansion.

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.abc) do (
    abc2xyz "%%~f"
    procxyz "%%~nf.xyz"
)
```

Note, the surrounding double quotes on the second command is important, if your file has a space, your file will not be processed.

You can test the actual results, without modifying them, by running the following:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.abc) do (
   echo "%%~f"
   echo "%%~nf.xyz"
)
```

You can read about variable expansion by running, from `for /?` from `cmd`, then scroll down and read the `substitution` section.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the filename of the %%f parameter in the second command. This can be done by the ~n change to the %%f parameter.
See for /? for the details and more info regarding this syntax.

```
for %%f in (*.abc) do (
    abc2xyz %%f
    procxyz %%~nf.xyz
    )
```